# How to print the image number after selecting from gallery in Flutter

Tags: flutter, image, dart, imagepicker

I am using `image_picker` library to get the image from gallery or camera along with the `path`. After selecting the image, the `path` i am getting is

> From Android:

```
file:///data/user/0/com.app.example/cache/image_picker3591192956415925225.jpg
```

> From iOS:

```
file:///private/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/9BC3C9D3-4A63-4DD0-B9C6-5C09AD7D0C17/tmp/image_picker_AAA27575-1B01-4154-A805-29C5219ADB89-1366-000000C4784B27EC.png
```

So my question is how to get the image number that is "number.png" (12345.png) ?

The code i am using to print path is:

```
final image = await ImagePicker().pickImage(source: ImageSource.gallery);
      if (image == null) {
        return;
      }
      final imageTemporary = File(image.path);
      print(imageTemporary.uri);
```

Comment: if you print image.path.toString().split("/").last.. it will print
image_picker3591192956415925225.jpg in Android
image_picker_AAA27575-1B01-4154-A805-29C5219ADB89-1366-000000C4784B27EC.png in IOS

Comment: You want to get file name or just numbers in the file name?

Comment: @Diwyansh Just numbers

Answer (score 0):

You need to get the `file name` first then you'll be able to `filter` the `numbers` in that `String`. I'm sharing a simple function you can even customize it.

to use **basename** you have to import **path.dart**

```
import 'package:path/path.dart';

getBase() {
  String abc = "data/user/0/com.app.example/cache/image_picker3591192956415925225.jpg";
  final name = basename(abc);
  print(name.replaceAll(RegExp(r'[^0-9]'),""));
}
```